# Using onclick with Google analytics and opening in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics, onclick

What I am trying to do here is upon clicking, the link opens in a new tab and Google Analytics tracks the event. I have all the necessary code for this to work.

```
<a style="color:#0A12FF;font-size:36px;font-family:Arial Black;text-decoration:underline;" 
   href=" https://pats-swedesboro.foodtecsolutions.com/menu" 
   onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;" 
   onclick="trackOutboundLink('https://pats-swedesboro.foodtecsolutions.com/menu');">
    Click Here
</a>
```

That is my current code. If I remove `onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;"` then Google Analytics properly tracks the event. However, I am trying to have both happen. Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can only have a single `onclick` attribute so you need to combine them, something like this perhaps:

```
onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');trackOutboundLink('https://pats-swedesboro.foodtecsolutions.com/menu');return false;"
```